# Reformulate this system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have the following systems of equations:

$$ A\cdot g = \mathbb 0\\
G\cdot \mathbb 1 = w$$

- $A$ is a $J\cdot I \times J\cdot I$ matrix.
- $g$ is a $J\cdot I \times 1$ column vector
- $\mathbb 0$ and $\mathbb 1$ are column vectors of zeros and ones of appropriate length ($J\cdot I\times 1$)
- $w$ is a column vector of weights (also $J\cdot I\times 1$)

$G$ is a reformulation of $g$. Let's index $g_x$ as the $x$'the row in $g$. Then $G$ is a $J\times I$ matrix:

$$ G = \begin{matrix}g_1 & g_2 & \cdots & g_{I} \\
g_{I+1} & g_{I+2} & \cdots & g_{2I}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
g_{(J-1)I+1} & \cdots & \cdots & g_{JI}\end{matrix}$$

Now, I have $A$ and $w$ given, and I look for $g$ that solves the system of equations. I'm failing to rewrite the system in a form that is easily solvable numerically. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) and [vectorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29). We have
$$\tag{1}g=\mathrm{vec}(G^T)\quad\text{and}\quad\mathrm{vec}(ABC)=(C^T\otimes A)\mathrm{vec}(B).$$
The equation $\boldsymbol{1}^TG^T=w^T$ (which is the transpose of the second $G\boldsymbol{1}=w$) is equivalent to 
$$\mathrm{vec}(\boldsymbol{1}^TG^T)=\mathrm{vec}(w^T)=w,$$ 
and hence can be written using (1) as 
$$
(E\otimes\boldsymbol{1}^T)g=w,
$$
where $E$ is the identity matrix. So the whole system can be written as
$$
\pmatrix{A\\E\otimes\boldsymbol{1}^T}g=\pmatrix{0\\w}.
$$

Comment: And the intermediate step being $vec(1^T G^T) = vec(1^T G^T E)$? I like the vectorization approach, something I was completely unfamiliar with.

Comment: @FooBar Exactly, you set $C=E$.